# automatic questionnaire generator problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've built this little program that generates 462 questions and it answers to them randomly with yes or no (image for reference).

Besides that, I have an array of numbers ArrayA

What I try to do next but can't figure out how it's to check if the first array(items) has matching elements with the second array (ArrayA). And if it does, add a "-1" to in the right of the matching number

So, if element from the first array  == element second array => add -1 to that element(number)

I hope you guys understand my code, image, and explanation. My English is not so good

The disired output is to have "-1" next to the elements from ArrayA

Here is the code:

```
var items = new Array(462); //create a 462 element array

var randMe = function ( me ) {
    if ( me ) {
        return me.sort(function() {
          return 0.5 - Math.random();
        })[0];
    }
}


var ArrayA = [53, 162, 179, 202, 207, 267, 303, 304 ];


for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){

    document.write( (i+1) + '.' + randMe(['yes','no']) +'<br/>');
}
```

And here is the output:[image]

Comment: `new Array(462);//create a 45 element array` ? how ?

Comment: `new Array(462);` create an array with  462 **undefined** elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.includes()`:

```js
var items = new Array(462); //create a 462 element array

var randMe = function(me) {
  if (me) {
    return me.sort(function() {
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    })[0];
  }
}

var ArrayA = [53, 162, 179, 202, 207, 267, 303, 304];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var curr = i+1;
  var randVal = randMe(['yes', 'no']);
  var str = ArrayA.includes(curr) ? 
            (curr) + '.' + randVal + (randVal === 'yes'?'-1':'') + '<br/>':
            (curr) + '.' + randVal + '<br/>'
  document.write(str);
}
```

Comment: you are a genius. Thank you so much. worked like a charm

Comment: one small problem that i forgot to mention. I want to add the "-1" only if the answer is YES. any idea how?

Comment: @Filu Edited the answer..for future reference, either include all info in 1 question or ask separate questions for separate issues

Comment: you are right. Thanks again! it worked!! Love you bro